# Foreign keys in CORE

Tags: asp.net-core

Using Community-2017 and imported the database but I am having an issue with the foreign keys. I have an error about not being part of the ICollection, and do not know what the means.

```
                entity.HasOne(d => d.SendObNoNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => ***p.EntSendingBuilding)***  <---
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.SendObNo)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_entSendingBuilding_entBuilding");
```

Comment: *what* error is it? Please always include the exact error message and not just "an error."

Answer (score 0):

This is because property EntSendingBuilding does not implement ICollection<>, for example, it is not an List<>.

Comment: So the error is that ICollection <EntBuilding> does not contain a definition for EntSendingBuilding and no extension method. But the Table definition for EntBuilding contains the following.     public virtual ICollection<EntSendingBuilding> EntSendingBuilding { get; set; }